# SAS proc surveymeans lognormal distribution

Tags: sas

I am trying to use SAS to estimate sigma of a variable.

Unweighted I use the following code:

```
proc univariate data=test1;
var grams;                          **unweighted but gives both estimates;
histogram / lognormal(zeta=EST sigma=EST);
run;
```

But since this is survey data I need to include the weights.
I am not sure how to include a variable with a log normal distribution to estimate sigma into the proc surveymeans statement. Or if I should be using proc survey means at all.

```
proc surveymeans data = test plots = histogram;
weight WTDRD1;
cluster Masked_variance_pseudo_PSU;
strata Masked_variance_pseudo_stratum;  
var grams;
run;
ods graphics off;
```

Code only estimates the mean using the survey weights. Not the sigma using the lognormal distribution.